# Pass elements to C# object - LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, object

Having issues trying to extract the values from the XML file below. I need the following values passed to a C# object: EXPR, DATE, ASK. I am going to use LINQ. I am having the issue with the EXPR value as it is not grouped and all I can get is the first value. Any ideas?

```
<RESPONSE>
    <EXPR>USD</EXPR>
    <EXCH>EUR</EXCH>
    <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
    <NPRICES>1</NPRICES>
    <CONVERSION>
        <DATE>Sat, 02 Jun 2001 22:50:00 GMT</DATE>
        <ASK>0.8484</ASK>
        <BID>0.8479</BID>
    </CONVERSION>
    <EXPR>USD</EXPR>
    <EXCH>CAD</EXCH>
    <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
    <NPRICES>1</NPRICES>
    <CONVERSION>
        <DATE>Sat, 02 Jun 2001 15:54:57 GMT</DATE>
        <ASK>0.6505</ASK>
        <BID>0.6501</BID>
    </CONVERSION>
    <EXPR>USD</EXPR>
    <EXCH>FRF</EXCH>
    <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
    <NPRICES>1</NPRICES>
    <CONVERSION>
        <DATE>Thu, 31 Dec 1998 00:00:00 GMT</DATE>
        <ASK>0.1779</ASK>
        <BID>0.1779</BID>
    </CONVERSION>
    <EXPR>USD</EXPR>
    <EXCH>DEM</EXCH>
    <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
    <NPRICES>1</NPRICES>
    <CONVERSION>
        <DATE>Thu, 31 Dec 1998 00:00:00 GMT</DATE>
        <ASK>0.5967</ASK>
        <BID>0.5964</BID>
    </CONVERSION>
</RESPONSE>
```

code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlUrl);

XmlNode GeneralInformationNode =
doc.SelectSingleNode("/RESPONSE");
foreach (XmlNode node in GeneralInformationNode)
{
   var currrates = new Rates();
   currrates.Currency_ID =
            GeneralInformationNode.SelectSingleNode("EXCH").InnerText;
   currrates.Sell_Rate =
           GeneralInformationNode.SelectSingleNode("EXPR").InnerText;
   Console.WriteLine(currrates.Currency_ID + currrates.Sell_Rate);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What's the query that you're using that isn't working?  Also, is it an option at all to fix the XML file to actually group all of the groupings into an element rather than tossing them all lose into the same response?

Comment: I cannot change the XML as it is form an external website. I have the following code:

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but I believe it will suit your needs.

First lets define objects to contain your data:

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string Expr { get; set; }
        public string Exch { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int NPrices { get; set; }
        public Conversion Conversion { get; set; }
    }
    public class Conversion
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Ask { get; set; }
        public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    }
```

Change names and types as approprate.
Now you can loop through, as long as the XML document is consistent in the order of its elements.

```
        var input = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("*Your XML here*");
        var output = new List<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Elements().Count(); i += 5)
        {
            var items = new System.Xml.Linq.XElement(
                 "group", input.Elements().Skip(i).Take(5));
            var item = new Data();
            output.Add(item);

            item.Expr = items.Element("EXPR").Value;
            item.Exch = items.Element("EXCH").Value;
            item.Amount = int.Parse(items.Element("AMOUNT").Value);
            item.NPrices = int.Parse(items.Element("NPRICES").Value);

            var conversion = items.Element("CONVERSION");
            item.Conversion = new Conversion();
            item.Conversion.Date = DateTime.Parse(conversion.Element("DATE").Value);
            item.Conversion.Ask = decimal.Parse(conversion.Element("ASK").Value);
            item.Conversion.Bid = decimal.Parse(conversion.Element("BID").Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there should be a unique `EXPR` value associated with each `CONVERSION`, this seems like bad XML.  That being said, I understand that you cannot change the XML you have.  If you are relying on the fact that an `EXPR` element precedes each `CONVERSION` element, you can rely on the LINQ method `Zip`.  Read the documentation of `Zip` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).  Your code might look something like this:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);
var exprs = xmlDoc.Descendants("EXPR");
var conversions = xmlDoc.Descendants("CONVERSION");
var structuredInfo = exprs.Zip(conversions, Tuple.Create)
   .Select(info => new { 
           Expr = info.Item1.Value, 
           Date = info.Item2.Element("DATE").Value,
           Ask = info.Item2.Element("ASK").Value
 });
```

Comment: +1 Interesting approach, but how would you handle if OP wanted the EXCH nodes too? Can you Zip more than 2 arrays?

Comment: @ChuckSavage Sure - you can zip the zipped `IEnumerable` with another `IEnumerable`.  I like to use `Tuples` in this context, but recall that `Zip` takes any "zipping" function as its second argument.  In the case you describe, you could do: `var newStructuredInfo = structuredInfo.Zip(exchs, (firstTuple, newExch) => Tuple.Create(firstTuple.Item1, firstTuple.Item2, newExch));`, where `exchs` is the extracted `EXCH` elements.  So we're extracting the elements of the first tuple and creating a new tuple with those items along with the new item.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's what I thought would be how to do it.  So there is no multi-arrays Zip built in to use the Tuple.Create which has up to 7 values it can use.

Comment: @ChuckSavage To my knowledge there is no such core method.  Making such an extension method wouldn't be too bad, though!  That would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your XML is as nonsensical as it is, the best I can do is get a list of `EXPR`s and a list of `CONVERSION` nodes, and associate them with each-other

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        List<string> EXPRs = xDoc.Element("RESPONSE").Elements("EXPR").Select( e => e.Value).ToList();
        List<XElement> CONVERSIONs = xDoc.Element("RESPONSE").Elements("CONVERSION").ToList();

        for(int i=0; i<EXPRs.Count; i++)
        {
            var currrates = new Rates();
            currrates.Currency_ID = EXPRs[i];
            currrates.DATE = CONVERSIONs[i].Element("DATE").Value;

            Console.WriteLine(currrates.Currency_ID + currrates.Sell_Rate);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: if you can include the `c# object` that you need to build from this, than I can make this answer more complete.

Comment: Thanks but it still only prints one EXPR and DATE. Does not iterate through.